# personalizar exportador de Excel

Tags: javascript, excel

Buenas tengo esta función que utilizo para exportar a excel.

```
function ExportToExcel(tabla) {
        var clone = tabla.clone();
        var trs = clone.find('tr');
        $.each(trs, function(i, tr) {

      $(tr).find('td:eq(13) li:nth-child(1)').remove();//status
      $(tr).find('td:eq(13) li:nth-child(2)').remove();
      $(tr).find('td:eq(13) li:nth-child(3)').remove();
      $(tr).find('td:eq(13) li:nth-child(4)').remove();
      $(tr).find('td:eq(13) li:nth-child(5)').remove(); 

      $(tr).find('td:eq(13) ul:nth-child(0)').remove();
      $(tr).find('td:eq(13) ul:nth-child(1)').remove();
       $(tr).find('td:eq(13) ul:nth-child(2)').remove();
      $(tr).find('td:eq(13) ul:nth-child(3)').remove();
       $(tr).find('td:eq(13) ul:nth-child(4)').remove();
      $(tr).find('td:eq(13) ul:nth-child(5)').remove();

      $(tr).find('td:eq(25)').remove();//eliminar
      $(tr).find('th:eq(25)').remove();


        });
        var htmlExport = clone.prop('outerHTML');
        var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
        var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

        //other browser not tested on IE 11
        // If Internet Explorer
        if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
            jQuery('body').append("<iframe id=\"iframeExport\" style=\"display:none\"></iframe>");
            iframeExport.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
            iframeExport.document.write(htmlExport);
            iframeExport.document.close();
            iframeExport.focus();
            sa = iframeExport.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, "Cotizaciones.xls");
        }
        else {
            var link = document.createElement('a');

            document.body.appendChild(link); // Firefox requires the link to be in the body
            link.download = "Cotizaciones.xls";
            link.href = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + escape(htmlExport);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    }
```

Todo lo hace bien, pero el detalle es que cuando se descarga y abro el documento Excel mi primera columna no aparece que seria mi encabezado, pero si la hago mas ancha la fila ahi aparece mi encabezado, hay alguna forma de darle como estilo a la fila para que ya me aparezca con un ancho predefinido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi me aparece en mi archivo excel tengo que hacer grande la fila 1 para que se vea.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar tu html para tener un [mcve]?

Comment: mi html solo es el id de la tabla todo lo hago en javascript, ya pude hacer lo del voton, solo me falta hacer q cuando cargue el archivo excel mi primera fila la haga grande porque lo esconde

Comment: tabla es del tipo HTMLElement, y no se ve en tu código en que momento lo asignas, igual sería bueno que incluyteras eso

Comment: pero lo raro es que tengo otra tabla igual pero con menos columnas y si las muestra bien, ya intente removerle columnas a mi tabla grande pero no lo hace y es el mismo codigo

Comment: Juan José me temo que para esto lo mejor sería usar una librería de terceros ([ver esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50595709/5587982)) o trabajarlo desde el servidor con [`PHPSpreadsheet`](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/).

Comment: Un archivo CSV ¿te resultaría útil? utilizas menos recursos, se abre con cualquier programa de hoja de cálculo (como Excel o Calc).

Comment: @Chofoteddy si podría funcionarme

Comment: @A.Cedano crees que si agregando una fila adicionar al inicio me muestre mi encabezado en la segunda fila?

Comment: No lo sé Juan José, habría que probar. De todos modos me parece un código algo precario y puede que según que cliente no funcione. En casos como estos es mejor usar una librería como `PHPSpreadsheet`