# Seleccionar tabla en PHP por variable

Tags: php, sql, variables

tengo mi web conectada a una base de datos, y selecciono una tabla poniéndola tal cual se llama, pero ahora tengo dividido por secciones, y capaz, lo que quiero mostrar está en otra tabla, y quiero cambiarlo directamente desde una variable: Pongo el ejemplo de como lo tengo y de lo que quiero hacer:

`$sql_dbpartidos = "SELECT * from equipos where id=0";`

Y quiero hacer algo así:

`$sql_dbpartidos = "SELECT * from $sqlPrincipal where id=0";`

Y en $sqlPrincipal defino la tabla que quiero seleccionar, y asi en todas las páginas, asi no tengo que ir cambiando una por una, se entiende?

Al dejarlo así me sale este error:

> [11-Dec-2018 20:11:55 America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires] PHP Warning: 
>   mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean
>   given in /home/adiccion/public_html/index.php on line 35

```html
$sql_dbpartidos = "SELECT * from $sqlPrincipal where id=0";
$result_dbpartidos = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql_dbpartidos);
(linea 35) $rows_dbpartidos = mysqli_fetch_array($result_dbpartidos);
if($rows_dbpartidos){                          
  echo '<title>Adiccion Futbolera - Ver ' . $rows_dbpartidos['equipo_local'] .  ' vs ' . $rows_dbpartidos['equipo_visitante'] .  ' </title>';
```

Comment: Está muy bien así. No veo cuál es el problema... `$sqlPrincipal` debe tener el valor de la tabla que quieres usar y esa tabla debe tener una columna llamada `id`.

Comment: ¿Está bien? Que raro, me corta toda la web, no veo el menu, no veo el "title", porque en el titulo llamo a datos de la base de datos

Comment: Si te corta toda la web puede ser por otra cosa en tu código. En cuanto a la práctica, si se cumplen las condiciones que dije en el anterior comentario, está bien. Otra cosa es que la lógica posterior del código coincida siempre con los datos que va a traer el `SELECT`

Comment: Ahí entre al "error_log" y me deja esto: `[11-Dec-2018 20:11:55 America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires] PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/adiccion/public_html/index.php on line 35
`

Comment: Ahí edito la pregunta, con el código completo y el error así es mas fácil.

Comment: Listo, ahí edité la pregunta, con todo lo que tengo.

Comment: Entonces dices que tal vez la consulta pueda estar mal? por que no le haces un echo

Comment: Me salta esto: SELECT * from where id=0, no toma la variable

Comment: Te hablé de dos condiciones que se deben cumplir: (1) la tabla que uses debe existir y (2) debe tener una columna llamada `id`. Entonces, ¿cuál es el valor de la variable `$sqlPrincipal `, es una tabla que existe?  ¿Tiene esa tabla una columna llamada `id`? ¿Dónde asignas un valor a la variable `$sqlPrincipal`?

Comment: entonces son las comillas que pones a la mejor no concatenas bien

Comment: Ya está, pasa que estas variables las tengo en otro archivo, y el include que trae ese archivo estaba abajo del SELECT * from ... ahora lo puse arriba y ya funciona, o eso parece

Comment: Claro claro, si el `include` estaba abajo claro que no iba a tomar el valor de `$sqlPrincipal`, es evidente.

Comment: @A.Cedano podrias ayudarme en un exportador de excel?

Comment: Si, no me di cuenta, pensé que estaba arriba, fue un error medio bobo

Comment: @JuanJose sugiero que plantees la pregunta aquí (si no lo has hecho ya) y yo u otro usuario con más experiencia en ese aspecto seguro que te echará una mano. Cuando la pregunta esté me puedes avisar y según lo que sea te digo en lo que esté a mi alcance ayudarte.

Comment: @A.Cedano si ya esta desde hace rato, https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/221305/personalizar-exportador-de-excel

Answer (score -1):

Parece que estás indicando la variable dentro de las comillas.

Prueba esto:

```
$sql_dbpartidos = "SELECT * from ".$sqlPrincipal." where id=0";
```

Comment: trata de agregar una explicacion a tu codigo, quiero invitarte a hacer el [tour] para asi puedas ganar algunas medallas